# ¿Cómo transformas una columna del diccionario en una dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, dataframe, diccionarios

Tengo un archivo csv con una columna que tiene los resultadosque me interesan y una otra el index:

```
,Province, Constituency Name, Party Affiliation, segments
0,Ben Slimane, Ain Tizgha, UND, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes': 5, 'total': 24, 'intention_rate': 20.83}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'No': 10, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 12, 'intention_rate': 8.33}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'Yes': 3, 'total': 4, 'intention_rate': 75}}"
1,Ben Slimane, Ain Tizgha, ABS, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes': 5, 'total': 24, 'intention_rate': 20.83}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'No': 10, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 12, 'intention_rate': 8.33}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'Yes': 3, 'total': 4, 'intention_rate': 75}}"
2,Ben Slimane, Ain Tizgha, PJD, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes': 5, 'total': 24, 'intention_rate': 20.83}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'No': 10, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 12, 'intention_rate': 8.33}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'Yes': 3, 'total': 4, 'intention_rate': 75}}"
3,Ben Slimane, Ahlaf, UND, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes': 5, 'total': 24, 'intention_rate': 20.83}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'No': 10, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 12, 'intention_rate': 8.33}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'Yes': 3, 'total': 4, 'intention_rate': 75}}"
4,Ben Slimane, Ahlaf, ABS, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes': 5, 'total': 24, 'intention_rate': 20.83}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'No': 10, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 12, 'intention_rate': 8.33}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'Yes': 3, 'total': 4, 'intention_rate': 75}}"
5,Ben Slimane, Ahlaf, PJD, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 16, 'No': 3, 'Yes': 5, 'total': 24, 'intention_rate': 20.83}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'No': 10, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 12, 'intention_rate': 8.33}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 1, 'Yes': 3, 'total': 4, 'intention_rate': 75}}"
6,Khouribga,Ain Kaicher,UND, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 46, 'No': 12, 'Yes': 13, 'total': 71, 'intention_rate': 18.31}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 4, 'No': 79, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 84, 'intention_rate': 1.19}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 14, 'No': 1, 'Yes': 4, 'total': 19, 'intention_rate': 21.05}}"
7,Khouribga,Ain Kaicher,ABS, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 46, 'No': 12, 'Yes': 13, 'total': 71, 'intention_rate': 18.31}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 4, 'No': 79, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 84, 'intention_rate': 1.19}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 14, 'No': 1, 'Yes': 4, 'total': 19, 'intention_rate': 21.05}}"
8,Khouribga,Ain Kaicher,PJD, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 46, 'No': 12, 'Yes': 13, 'total': 71, 'intention_rate': 18.31}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 4, 'No': 79, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 84, 'intention_rate': 1.19}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 14, 'No': 1, 'Yes': 4, 'total': 19, 'intention_rate': 21.05}}"
9, Khouribga,Bni Bataou,UND, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 46, 'No': 12, 'Yes': 13, 'total': 71, 'intention_rate': 18.31}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 4, 'No': 79, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 84, 'intention_rate': 1.19}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 14, 'No': 1, 'Yes': 4, 'total': 19, 'intention_rate': 21.05}}"
10, Khouribga,Bni Bataou,ABS, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 46, 'No': 12, 'Yes': 13, 'total': 71, 'intention_rate': 18.31}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 4, 'No': 79, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 84, 'intention_rate': 1.19}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 14, 'No': 1, 'Yes': 4, 'total': 19, 'intention_rate': 21.05}}"
11, Khouribga,Bni Bataou,PJD, "{'UND': {""I don't know yet"": 46, 'No': 12, 'Yes': 13, 'total': 71, 'intention_rate': 18.31}, 'ABS': {""I don't know yet"": 4, 'No': 79, 'Yes': 1, 'total': 84, 'intention_rate': 1.19}, 'PJD': {""I don't know yet"": 14, 'No': 1, 'Yes': 4, 'total': 19, 'intention_rate': 21.05}}"
```

En efecto, hay duplicados. Ojalá tuviera algo así:

```
Constituency,UND, ABS, PJD
Ain Tizgha,20.83,32,0,
Ahlaf,20.83,38,0
Ain Kaicher,18.31, 1.19, 21.05
Bni Bataou,18.31, 1.19, 21.05
```

Los numeros serian los intention_rate de cada de lost elementos en los diccionarios de la columna segments.

¿Cómo transformas una columna del diccionario en una dataframe?

Por lo momento intenté hacerlo dinamicamente en el archivo original:

```
def parse_segment(row):
    segment = row['segments']
    segment = ast.literal_eval(segment)
    results = []
    for party in df['Party Affiliation'].unique():
        if party in segment.keys():
            v_i = segment[party]['intention_rate']
            results.append(v_i)
        else:
            v_i = 0
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main()
    # Load data
    df = pd.read_csv('constituencies_with_segments.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
    parties = [party for party in df['Party Affiliation'].unique()]
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Constituency Name', 'segments'], inplace=True)

    df[parties] = df.apply(parse_segment, axis=1, result_type='expand')
    df.drop(columns=['Province', 'Party Affiliation', 'segments'], inplace=True)
    print(df.head())
```

Sin embargo, algunas liberaciones no han dado resultados, por lo que no están presentes en el diccionario para una línea determinada. Es por eso que me da lo siguiente, por supuesto:

```
(campaign_manager) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\electoral-prediction-model-pk\data\Morocco>python3 geojson_file_updater.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geojson_file_updater.py", line 75, in <module>
    df[parties] = df.apply(parse_segment, axis=1, result_type='expand')
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2935, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_array(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2961, in _setitem_array
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Sin embargo, de una manera no dinámica, lo hago. Pero preferiría tener algo dinámico en las partes porque en mi expediente real tengo varios, algunos de ellos presentes en una circunscripción, otros no.

Comment: Hola, si tu CSV es tal y como muestras, el mayor problema que veo es que realmente no tienes ni la representación válida de un diccionario, ni un JSON válido, ni siquiera un HJSON, la causa es `{""I don't know yet"": 1, ...}` que es equivalente realmente `{I don't know yet: 1, ...}`, cuando debería ser `{"I don't know yet": 1, ...}`

Comment: @FJSevilla ¡Hola, FJ! Sí, esta es la forma de mi archivo, por desgracia.

Comment: @FJSevilla Pero `fout.write(line.replace('""', '"'))` ¿no sería suficiente?